# Refresh div content on form submit (ajax)

Tags: php, jquery

On my page I have a form that inserts a new record in to the database. On the same page there is a DIV that contains the current resultset.

What I am trying to do is refresh just that DIV (not the whole page) when the form is submitted. The DIV will then contain the latest records (including the one just added).

```
$('#add-variants-form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/addvariants',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
    });

    return false;
});

<div id="current-rows">
<?php while($variant=mysql_fetch_array($variants)) { ?>
    <div class="row">
    // resultset        
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

I set `$variants` from within my controller (beforehand):

```
$variants=Catalog::getProductVariants($product['id']);
```

Ideally I don't want to be returning a whole load of HTML to be injected in to that DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put the contents of the "current-rows" div into it's own seperate view file:

```
<div id="current-rows">
    <?php include("_current-rows.php"); ?>
</div>
```

And in my controller 'addvariants' action I just do this:

```
$variants=Catalog::getProductVariants($_POST['product_id']);
include('application/view/admin/catalog/_current-rows.php');
```

That is the response that is passed back to my jQuery success function.

Answer (score 1):

Set the new content in the success handler of ajax request. Try this

```
$('#add-variants-form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/addvariants',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(newContent){
            $('#current-rows').html(newContent);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to use .load method, which injects the response from the server to the given div, something like:

```
$('#idOfYourDiv').load('/your/url', {params: params});
```

alternatively you can still use $.ajax, like:

```
$('#add-variants-form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/addvariants',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
         $('#yourDiv').html(data); // html will insert response, response is stored in "data" variable
      }
    });
   return false;
});
```

on php site just echo what you want to be displayed, for example

```
foreach($results as $result){
  echo $result."<br />";
}
```

hope that helps